# Retrieving values based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, where-clause

Please have a look at the below query.

```
SELECT `p_id`, COUNT(`p_id`) AS OverlapWords, `UniqueWordCount`, 
(COUNT(`p_id`)/`UniqueWordCount`) AS SimScore FROM `key_uniqueword` WHERE `word` IN 
('stand','on') GROUP BY (`p_id`) LIMIT 500
```

I need to convert the `SimScore` into percentage and get all the records where `SimScore` is less than 90%. How can I do this in SQL? Last time when I did that it threw me an error something like `Invalid use of Group function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT `p_id`, COUNT(`p_id`) AS OverlapWords, `UniqueWordCount`, 
       (COUNT(`p_id`)/`UniqueWordCount`) AS SimScore
FROM `key_uniqueword`
WHERE `word` IN ('stand','on')
GROUP BY (`p_id`)
HAVING SimScore < 0.9
LIMIT 500;
```

Conditions on the result of an aggregation function belong in the `having` clause, not the `where` clause.